# How would insulate/fill this large enclosed area behind my gas fireplace

Tags: bathroom, insulation, fireplace, interior

I’m currently remolding most of my bathroom because I found some black mold behind a shower tile and then there just kept being moisture the more I uncovered. After opening the wall behind my fireplace, I discovered a large open space and i’m unsure of the proper way to tackle this. I feel the brick is poorly laid, I don’t know for sure since it’s my first time seeing the back of a fireplace. But I believe it use to be a wood burning fireplace that was converted to a gas fireplace and maybe that’s the reason. I don’t know if I should address the issues (if their are any) with the brick. And then how to go about filling the area. I was thinking of just slowly layering spray foam insulation and sealant. But I know the spray foam is flammable and shouldn’t be exposed to temperatures above 240 degrees F. And I’m not sure if any gaps behind the fireplace aid in any oxygen support for the fire to burn properly. I apologize for the long question/description I was just hoping to be discriptive enough to be helped. Hope I didn’t miss anything thank you in advance for you time and help. I’m also not opposed to removing it if that’s the best solution.

Images to follow shortly. After I figure out how to make them less MBs. Also the brick doesn’t look as bad as I remembered while writing this. And the also in quite as large as I remembered either… but I think it’s all still not great and rather roomy.

Also i’m From Minnesota and now live in southeast Texas so the fire place doesn’t get used.

[image: Inside bathroom wall 1]
[image: Inside bathroom wall 3]
[image: Inside bathroom wall 4]
[image: Inside bathroom wall 5]
[image: Inside bathroom wall 6]
[image: Inside bathroom wall 7]
[image: Inside bathroom wall 8]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need those images; if you're trying to post PNG images I find that JPEGs are much smaller.

Comment: Thank you! I’m excited I stumbled upon this place somehow! I added a link to them. To a shared iCloud album of the pictures. Those should be normal quality. Working on making them smaller still so I can have them here for those who don’t like to click on links

Comment: Alright sir I added the pictures to my original post. I apologize for the long delay.

Comment: One hour isn't a long delay! Thanks: it's a lot easier to understand now. I don't have any good answer for you, but hopefully one of our construction experts will.